# How to make an abstract class non-abstract with Javassist?

Tags: java, classloader, javassist

In a small framework I am building, I would like to change certain abstract classes to non-abstract using Javassist.
I already transformed all the abstract methods in non-abstract ones implementing the dynamically generated code I need. But I have not yet succeed in making the class non-abstract.
What I have tried is something similar to this:

Let's say `c` is the class I would like to make non abstract. So I have written:

```
public void instrument(Class c) {
    ...//some ignored exception management
    CtClass ctClass = ClassPool.getDefault().get(c.getName());
    ctClass.setModifiers(c.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.ABSTRACT);  
    return ctClass.toClass().newInstance();
}
```

However, the call to:

```
ctClass.toClass();
```

is raising the following `CannotCompileException`:

```
"attempted  duplicate class definition for name: <class_name>."
```

This is because the class has already been loaded, since I am invoking its `getName` method. It seems to me this is the only mechanism I have to get a `CtClass` from an existing class, but please someone tell me if that is not correct. Hardcoding the name of the class instead of calling its `getName` method is far from been an ideal solution, given that I need to apply this routine to many classes.

Any workaround to do this ?. If it is not possible at all I will dynamically generate a new class that extends the abstract class, implements its constructors, and the abstract method of all its ancestors (a bit more complicated, so I would be very happy if I succeed just making the original class non-abstrat instead).

Comment: Why do you need to implement methods at runtime like this?

Comment: trying to make a long story short: I am instrumenting certain classes so certain -abstract- methods in them will be automatically translated into queries to a prolog engine. These calls are defined by certain annotations in the methods.

Comment: Ok. I'm asking because it's an add use case. I'm not sure how you'd fix it, but it may be possible to do something else. E.g. is there any reason you can't generate implementation classes of these at compile time rather than at runtime?

Comment: no idea how to do it a compile time, do you mean creating classes in the file system and putting these classes in the classpath ? is this easier than generating classes all in memory at runtime ?

Comment: I'd say it depends on whether you'll be using the same classes over again or not. If the Classes are different depending on unpredictable circumstances you have to do it at runtime, otherwise I'd prefer build time primarily because I can then inspect and step through the code if I need to. It's fairly common practice to generate code at build time (there are different ways depending on what you're generating, you could use an annotation processor, some API or code it yourself).

Comment: yes, I will be using the same classes, and it could speed up the execution. I think I will do it in the future since it seems to be a bit more complicated than generating the classes at runtime. Which annotation processor or equivalent tool would you recommend me to try for the generation of classes at build time ?. What I am doing is part of an eclipse plugin, maybe there are eclipse tools that do this ?.

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't got any good suggestions for you as most code generation tools are highly specialised. I'd do some googling to see if you can find something that fits your needs unless it's relatively simple in which case you could just create a template file that you can process using `ant` or something similar. (If you're using `ant`, the `replace` target is very useful http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as you described it, is that you have already loaded the `Class` you are attempting to redefine.  It is illegal to attempt to redefine a class that is already loaded by a classloader.

One option might be to do a bit of classloader trickery: create a new classloader that doesn't have your existing classes loaded (parent is the system classloader) and have Javassist load through that (use a`CtClass.toClass()` method [that takes a `ClassLoader` argument](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/html/javassist/ClassPool.html#toClass%28javassist.CtClass,%20java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.security.ProtectionDomain%29)).

As it has suggested, there might be a better way to achieve your goal, and creating subclasses might be a better design.  Is using interfaces instead of abstract classes an option?  If so, [dynamic proxies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html) is an option as well, their advantage being you don't need any 3rd party libraries to create them.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @prunge. Question: if I use another classloader to load a modified version of my class, I will have two different versions of the same class in different class loaders, isnt it? there is no way to unload a class from a classloader?. I find annoying I cannot create a CtClass object from a not-yet-loaded Class object, that will be loaded the second I call getName() precisely to create a CtClass object.

Comment: @Sergio absolutely, you need to manage your classloaders carefully, especially if you start casting objects in the calling code.  You can also create a CtClass from a `String` name (but you lose benefit of compile-time safety).  As soon as you have a `Class` object the class has been loaded and you can no longer modify it.

Comment: do you know if with ASM I should be able to modify an already loaded class ? or that is a general restriction of the jvm and no library can do that ?

Comment: @Sergio once a classloader has loaded a class, it cannot be reloaded.  The only way is to load the updated class from a new classloader and use that.  Why? - think of the scenario where you incompatibily modify a class (remove or add a field) - what would happen to all objects of that class that already exist in memory?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried creating an extending Class rather than changing the existing Class? So create a Class, implement all the methods and use `setSuperClass()` to make it extend your abstract Class.

Comment: this is what I am doing in the meanwhile, in case I cannot find a solution to the question. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If that works, why would you specifically want to alter the abstract Class? Extending Classes are the way abstract Classes are designed to work after all.

Comment: just because it was easier (and faster) to change the abstract class as non abstract. I know that conceptually a better solution is indeed dynamically creating a new class extending the abstract one and overriding the appropriate methods and constructors.